# run a program to another pc using VB6

Tags: shell, vb6, winsock

i am searching for weeks now, and eventually joined lots of forums because i can't seem to find a way in finding help for the code i want. don't know the right term on how to search this. 
here is what i want to achieve, new to VB6, i have discovered the shell function to run a specific program, but what i want is, 
to run a program to a certain pc.
for example, 
shell ("//pc-9pc//directory/sample.exe")
when i run it, the exe file runs in my computer, what i want is for it to run in pc9.

is there a solution for this? is it under shell method?
pls help. i really need to create this for my project.
i've also seen winsock, but it seems that its only capable of chatting.
thanks cheers

Comment: sorry, but its the only thing i know, and that's what my teacher taught me. do you have any other way? but, i really need it to be in vb6, because we committed its use for our project. what i am trying to make, is a cafe timer. but for now, i am trying to achieve on how to run the .exe file on a pc i want with the command in the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: Attached is a sample of Server/Client Winsock with capability of executing a program remotely (both source code and executable included in the file)

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14773478/SERVER_CLIENT.zip

Shell will only execute a program on the local machine.

If you need to execute a program remotely then you will need some sort of peer-to-peer programming to tell the other peer to (execute) a certain program.  Winsock is a perfect example of how you would achieve that.

Create a server version of Winsock and set it to start listening to a connection request over a certain port. Then create a client version on your local pc and set it to connect to the remote IP or hostname on the selected port number.

After the connection is made, there is no limit to what you can do afterwards. You can program the server side socket to wait for messages like "`Shell c:\program\file.exe`" or something you define and customize to your needs. The server side then picks up the message and executes the program.

To help you with your requirement, I have done something like that, using only WinSock controls. I advise you to research more on Sockets, try to set up a chat program first. If you succeeded in that, then you are ready to move on to executing programs remotely.

Comment: thank you for that info! i am not used to winsock as of now, but i have downloaded some winsock chatting schemes. for server and for client, separated. do i need to study it? or can i just edit it like the one you are saying. i've a lot of winsock commands in google, but the thing is, when i click it, it only results to chatting, also, i don't know where to start, so if i've got a server client chat running now, what shall i do next?

Comment: If you can host a server Winsock program on the remote pc, and you are able to connect to it from your local pc, and begin chatting, then all you need to do is intercept the messages on the server and instead of telling the server to display the message, tell it to execute the command, using "shell". Is that clear, or do you need more explanation?

Comment: that seems to be okay, but i have tried the chatting code from this site [link]http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/client-server-chat-program-using-winsock-control-tutorial[/link]
its working when i try opening 2 vb projects. but when i use 2 pc's, they can't seem to connect. do you know the problem?

Comment: @LeisFernandez .. Please see my updated Answer. I attached a sample of my programming with Sockets, I hope it will give you push in the right direction

Comment: lol, i know that vb6 is an old version, the thing is, we committed in using that language to create my program, besides, mr. Ahmad seems to have a way. :)

Comment: WOW! thank you so much for the HELP!!!! i really appreciated it! thank you! now, the only problem is, if its going to work in two computers :) still thanks alot!

Comment: another thing, can i use this?  *("c:\directory\file.exe")
when i try, it says, file not found.

Comment: You are welcome. What do you mean by (going to work in two computers)? Do you mean to run the server and start accepting commands from several clients? If that is the case, yes it is possible. You just need to re-write how the server accepts connection requests and make listening to new requests permanent.

Comment: try:  `*"c:\directory\file.exe"`

Comment: holy **** man. you just made me jump. if only i could thank you personally! haha! you are the best! 
thanks, this is the only thing that i need, so the rest is up to me. :P
can i also do this vice versa? because the server client needs to the one sending the command. lol either way.this is greatly appreciated. i'll try to ask again if there is something i don't understand :)

Comment: hi, i cannot post another question, the site says i did meet the req. something like that, i want to ask you what seems to be the problem when its not connecting on a computer?
it connected to pc2, but it did not on pc5. firewalls are off too. thanks

Comment: @LeisFernandez I am sorry for the late response. Do you still need help with this question?